# Как написать вложенный цикл?

Tags: sql-server

Хочу написать цикл, чтобы для первой итерации первого цикла, внутренний цикл выполнился 5 раз.

```
DECLARE @counter1 INT = 1,
        @counter2 INT = 1;

WHILE @counter1 <= 6
BEGIN
    WHILE @counter2 <= 5
    BEGIN
        PRINT @counter2
        SET @counter2 += 1;
    END
    PRINT @counter1
    SET @counter1 += 1;
END
```

Вывод, который я хочу получить: `1 1 2 3 4 5 2 1 2 3 4 5` и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @number1 INT,
        @number2 INT

SET @number1 = 1
SET @number2 = 1

WHILE @number1 <= 10
    BEGIN
        PRINT CONCAT('@number1 - ', @number1)
        SET @number1 = @number1 + 1

        WHILE @number2 <= 5
            BEGIN
                PRINT CONCAT('@number2 - ', @number2)
                SET @number2 = @number2 + 1
            END
        SET @number2 = 1
    END;
```